# Passing variable by reference in python

Tags: python, binary-tree, pass-by-reference

I am practicing a leetcode question and I am having trouble updating my variable. I think I am not passing my reference correctly. I am expecting the answer to be 3 but I am getting 1. I ran through the code and the answer 3 is achieved but when i jump back out of my recursion I am getting 1.

The goal is the find the longest consecutive chain of nodes in a binary tree.

ex:

```
1
 \
  3
 / \
2   4
     \
      5
```

Answer would be 3 --> 3,4,5

Below is the runnable code:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution(object):
    def DFS(self, root):
        count = 0
        if root:
            count += 1
            q = [root]
            while q:
                n = q.pop()
                T = 0
                if n.left:
                    if n.left.val == n.val + 1:
                        q.append(n.left)
                        T = 1
                if n.right:
                    if n.right.val == n.val + 1:
                        q.append(n.right)
                        T = 1
                if T:
                    count += 1
        return count

    def longestConsecutive(self, root, count=0):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        c = count
        if root:
            c = max(c, self.DFS(root))
            self.longestConsecutive(root.left, c)
            self.longestConsecutive(root.right, c)
        return c

a = Node(1)
b = Node(3)
c = Node(2)
d = Node(4)
e = Node(5)

a.right = b
b.left = c; b.right = d
d.right = e

poop = Solution()
print(poop.longestConsecutive(a))
```

Comment: You will get better and faster answers if you produce a minimal example of the problem, without all the unrelated logic around it. If you're unsure about your DFS implementation, post that as a separate question

Comment: You can't pass variables by reference in Python. In fact, you never pass variables around at all; you can only pass objects.

Comment: Technically, Python does not support pass-by-reference semantics.

Comment: You're using `T`, an int variable, as a boolean flag. Just use `True` and `False`.

Comment: @user2357112 you assign objects to names

Comment: Passing variables by reference is actually though to a limited extent. Robert Heaton nicely elaborates this in this article http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Comment: @Michael that's a broken link, but I've read that article before, and it does not make the case that pass-by-reference is possible in Python, rather, it explains the *difference* between Python's evaluation strategy and call-by-reference. This evaluation strategy is sometimes called "pass by object reference", sometimes "pass by assignment", although technically it is [call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). In any event, it is *not the same as call-by-reference*. If call-by-reference was possible in Python, you could write a `swap` function.

Answer (score 3):

You're returning `count` from the `longestConsecutive` method but not assigning it to anything. Try this instead:

```
def longestConsecutive(self, root, count=0):
    """
    :type root: TreeNode
    :rtype: int
    """
    c = count
    if root:
        c = max(c, self.DFS(root))
        c = self.longestConsecutive(root.left, c)
        c = self.longestConsecutive(root.right, c)
    return c
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the the value of `c` is not saved. While inside of your recursive calls, the value of `c` is correctly set to `3`. But when control flow begins to move back up the recursive stack, the value of `c` is lost. To fix this, you can make `c` an attribute of `Solutions`. That way, the value of `c` can be saved through out your recursive calls.

```
def longestConsecutive(self, root, count=0):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: int
        """
        self.c = count # make c an attribute of Solution.
        if root:
            self.c = max(self.c, self.DFS(root))
            self.longestConsecutive(root.left, self.c)
            self.longestConsecutive(root.right, self.c)
        return self.c
```

Which has the output:

```
3
```